# How to call object's member function from another function on that object (POJSO)

Tags: javascript

How can I call `afunc()` from `abfunc()`?

```js
const someFunctions = {
  afunc: () => {
    return 'A';
  },

  abfunc: () => {
    return afunc() + 'B';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` if you trade the arrow functions for the older syntax.

```js
const someFunctions = {
  afunc: function() {
    return 'A';
  },

  abfunc: function() {
    return this.afunc() + 'B';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just using the variable name itself (in your simple case here) works:

```
const someFunctions = {
  afunc: () => {
    return 'A';
  },

  abfunc: () => {
    return someFunctions.afunc() + 'B';
  }
}

someFunctions.abfunc();
```